# Stargazer table showing some variables twice, where they should only be displayed once

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a table that compares four models with each other. Here are the lines of code used to create each of the four models, as well as the table

model1

```
waterModel<-lm(water_datav2$WaterPlusSewer~water_datav2$Transparency+water_datav2$LogPop+water_datav2$GW)
```

model 2

```
waterModelRobSE<-lmrob(waterModel)
```

model 3

```
waterModelMinOutliers<- lm(WaterPlusSewer~Transparency+LogPop+GW, data=water_datav2[water_datav2$.cooksd<CDT,])
```

model 4

```
waterModelNoOutliersRbst<-lmrob(waterModelMinOutliers)
```

and the table:

```
stargazer(waterModel, waterModelRobSE, waterModelMinOutliers, waterModelNoOutliersRbst,
type = "text", no.space = TRUE, covariate.labels = NULL,label = "", omit.stat = c("f", "ser"), model.names=FALSE, dep.var.labels.include=FALSE,dep.var.caption="", column.labels=c("Raw Model", "Model with Robust SE", "Model without outliers", "model without outliers and with robust se"))
```

I expect the table made to compare them all neatly, and it almost does.

Here is what the actual table created looks like:

[image]

Why are the variables repeating?

Comment: The number of observations between model (1)-(2) and (3)-(4) are different, so you're not supposed to compare the coefficients directly even though the variables have the same name. I think `stargazer` is just being careful when making this separation.

Comment: Is there some way I can make them compare anyway? Or do I just have to use this malformed looking table?